# Verifying readonly property for an input field using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Please consider me a noob as I am still learning puppeteer.

I am writing a test to verify that the following input field has the **readonly** property to stop end-users from modifying it.

```
<input readonly id="serverUrl" type="text" value="https://mytestservice.com/">
```

I have tried several methods to achieve this but my methods are returning either undefined or false e.g.

```
let inputField = await page.$('#serverUrl')
const is_readonly = await (await inputField.getProperty("readonly")).jsonValue();
```

The above returns `undefined`.

Since I have fetched a radio button's disabled property using the following method, I thought I can do the same with the input field to verify the readonly property, by using the following:

```
const is_readonly = await page.$('#serverUrl[readonly]') !== null;
```

This resulted in `false` for the above-mentioned input field.

I have then run the same method on another field that does not have the readonly property the result for that field was also false.

```
is_readyonly value is : false
```

Can someone please elaborate on what I am doing wrong or how to resolve it, any help will be greatly appreciated, please?

Comment: Your `const is_readonly = await page.$('#serverUrl[readonly]') !== null;` works for me on https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/, loading https://output.jsbin.com/bahaxinebu. I get `true` with the HTML you've shown. If I change it so look for an attribute I know isn't there, i get `false`. So it seems to work. Perhaps you have more than one element with `id="serverUrl"`? `$` would only find the first.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it worked. Thanks for pointing out the possible issue. It was certainly the case of duplicate `id="serverUrl"` in the DOM.

Comment: The thing is, `const is_readonly = await page.$('#serverUrl[readonly]') !== null;` should work even if there's more than one `id="serverUrl"` element in the page, provided at least one of them has the `readonly` attribute. So I don't understand why it didn't work. (It would explain why your version with `getProperty` didn't work, but not why that version didn't work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the property is specified as `readOnly` instead of `readonly`. From the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#dom-input-readonly):

> The readOnly IDL attribute must reflect the readonly content attribute

So you need to spell it with a capital O:

```
const is_readonly = await (await inputField.getProperty("readOnly")).jsonValue();
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why `const is_readonly = await page.$('#serverUrl[readonly]') !== null;` also didn't work. (It does work for me with the HTML the OP shows.)

Comment: @Gh05d also your proposed solution with a capital `O` in the `readOnly` property is also working fine. Thanks for your help. 
`const is_readonly = await (await inputField.getProperty("readOnly")).jsonValue();`